# Pandas MultiIndex Lookup By Equality and Set Membership

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas `Series`, or `Dataframe`, with a multiindex:

```
first_key = ['a', 'b', 'c']
second_key = [1, 2, 3]

m_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([first_key, second_key],
                                     names=['first_key', 'second_key'])

series_with_index = pd.Series(0.0, index=m_index)
```

**How can the MultiIndex be indexed to lookup an equality for the first level and an `isin` on the second index?**

For example, how can all values where the first level is equal to `a` and the second level is in the set `{2, 3, 4}` be set to `1.0`?

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

you can use `index.get_level_values()` to find all the values in the first level that equal `a`.

`index.isin()` has a level parameter, so you can pass your set into that.

lastly change the values in the series to 1 where they are both True

```
m1 = series_with_index.index.get_level_values(0) == 'a'
m2 = series_with_index.index.isin({2,3,4},level=1)

series_with_index.mask(m1 & m2,1)
```

Output:

```
first_key  second_key
a          1             0.0
           2             1.0
           3             1.0
b          1             0.0
           2             0.0
           3             0.0
c          1             0.0
           2             0.0
           3             0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

With composite conditions for each of 2 levels:

```
s = pd.Series(0.0, index=m_index)
s[(s.index.get_level_values(0) == 'a') & ((s.index.get_level_values(1).isin({2, 3, 4})))] = 1.0
```

---

```
first_key  second_key
a          1             0.0
           2             1.0
           3             1.0
b          1             0.0
           2             0.0
           3             0.0
c          1             0.0
           2             0.0
           3             0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) and perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m1 = series_with_index.index.get_level_values('first_key')=='a'
m2 = series_with_index.index.get_level_values('second_key').isin([2,3,4])
series_with_index[m1&m2] = 1
```

Updated Series:

```
first_key  second_key
a          1             0.0
           2             1.0
           3             1.0
b          1             0.0
           2             0.0
           3             0.0
c          1             0.0
           2             0.0
           3             0.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

`query` works with named index, but only available for DataFrame:

```
my_set = {2, 3, 4}
series_with_index.to_frame()\
    .query('first_key=="a" & second_key in @my_set')
    .iloc[:,0]
```